# Proving $g_x-g_y=g_{x-y}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C:X\to X^{**}$ be defined by $x\to g_x$. My book (Kreyszig) says $g_x-g_y=g_{x-y}$. I wonder how that is.

$g_x=f(x)$ for all $f\in X^*$. Let $X^*=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,\dots\}$. Then $g_x=\{f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),\dots\}$. Similarly, $g_y=\{f_1(y),f_2(y),f_3(y),\dots\}$.

Hence, $g_x-g_y$is the set of all possible combinations of $f_i(x)-f_j(y)$ for $i,j\in\Bbb{N}$.

However, $g_{x-y}$ is just the set of elements $\{f_1(x-y),f_2(x-y),\dots\}$. How are the two sets the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll first make an attempt to clarify the question; I think you've misunderstood what $g_x$ is. First, be careful when writing the definition of $g_x$: if $g_x$ is an element of $X^{**}$, it should be a function that sends elements of $X^*$ into the real / complex numbers; so by definition, if $f \in X^*$,

$$g_x(f) = f(x)$$

Likewise,

$$g_x = \{f_1(x), f_2(x), \dots\}$$
is not correct. $g_x$ must be a function, not a set of numbers.

The other issue is that writing $X^* = \{f_1, f_2, ...\}$ implicitly assumes that $X^*$ is countable, and it's not.

---

Given all that, the question is to show that *as functions*, we have

$$g_x - g_y = g_{x - y}$$

To prove this, fix an arbitrary $f \in X^*$ and compute

$$\Big(g_x - g_y\Big)(f)$$

and

$$g_{x - y}(f)$$

and verify that they are equal.

Comment: Thanks! That clarified a major misconception.